# Remove the sort from a DataGrid column header through the UI

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

Is there a way to remove the Sort from a `DataGrid` column header using just the UI?

Currently, I have a button that clears the `PagedCollectionView`'s `SortDescriptions`

example

```
delegate
{
  CollectionView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Blend SDK's [`CallMethodAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.callmethodaction%28v=expression.40%29.aspx).  Should look something like this:

```
<Button Content="Clear Sort"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <ei:CallMethodAction 
                TargetObject="{Binding CollectionView.SortDescriptions}"
                MethodName="Clear" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: Interesting, is there a way to apply this to the `DataGridTextColumn` element?

Comment: @Aducci I'm failing to understand.  Can you give an example?